# Nested routes with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So currently im trying to make an app where each user has its own todo list with its own index page, which means, everybody is able to visit the user page to see each tasks of the user.

I use devise and created a simple model with a user reference:

```
rails g model Todo title:string completed:boolean user:references
```

added of course belongs_to / has_many to todo.rb/user.rb

Now since i want each todo index page to be assiociated with the users todos, i've created a nested resource like so:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :todos
  end
```

visiting

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/todos/
```

works fine and shows the index page.

Heres the problem: when i change the number after /users/ to, for example, 2, its still working, even though there is no user with the id of 2.

Any ideas how i can make this dynamic, so that the integer after /users/ represents the user_id? Thought i did it right but i guess im missing something. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

as requested, TodosController.rb:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def show
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @user = @todo.user
  end

  def update
  end

  def edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Please, add code of TodosController index action (or where is your action for http://localhost:3000/users/1/todos/)

Comment: Added the TodosController. However, if i change the number behind /todos/ to 2, 3, whatever, it works just fine, i get the message that the todo is missing with the id. But what doesn't work is the integer for user_id, as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: You are looking for the Todo id and not User id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let look at your index action:

```
def index
  @todos = Todo.all
end
```

It displays all todos always, because it doesn't know anything about the user. 
It should be:

```
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @todos = @user.todos
end
```

And in the show action you have to find the user at first, in this case you're sure, that the requested todo belongs to the requested user

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @todo = @user.todos.find(params[:id])
end
```

You can refactor out `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` to the before_action callback, because you'll use it in all actions